# Bootstrap4 cards are going out of container area

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

My boostrap `card-columns` are going out of container area even though I specify the card column count. Is there a way to fix it?

my CSS:

```
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 5;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(md) {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(sm) {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}


<div class="card-columns">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="card">
    <%= image_pack_tag product.image, class: "card-img-top" %>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"><%= product.name %></h5>
      <p class="card-text"><%= sanitize(product.description) %></p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="price"><%= sprintf("$%0.02f", product.price) %></small></p>

        <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product), class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
      
    </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

[Image here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsWU2.jpg)

Comment: It seems that `cards` have some extra margins.

Comment: Adjust the margin.  You can even try a negative margin.  Test in all devices after each pixel is changed.